# Error in installing package hydroTSM on Mac OS X 10.9.5 - R (version 3.1.2)

Tags: r, macos, installation

I have searched for hints to my problem and made some progress through hints from similar posts, but ultimately still stuck. I am trying to install the package hydroTSM on a Mac (OS X 10.9.5). Using R Studio I successfully installed and loaded the most recent zoo and xts packages (dependencies). I tried:

```
install.packages("hydroTSM", lib="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library", type="source")
```

and it the install seems to proceed Ok until it gets to installing the rgeos package, and I get:

```
* installing *source* package ‘rgeos’ ...
** package ‘rgeos’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++
configure: rgeos: 0.3-4
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 460
checking geos-config usability... 
./configure: line 2056: geos-config: command not found
no
configure: error: geos-config not usable
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rgeos’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rgeos’ is not available for package ‘spacetime’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/spacetime’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘spacetime’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘spacetime’ is not available for package ‘gstat’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/gstat’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gstat’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gstat’ is not available for package ‘automap’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/automap’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘automap’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘gstat’, ‘automap’ are not available for package ‘hydroTSM’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/hydroTSM’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hydroTSM’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in

‘/private/var/folders/87/wn7lf03j7w39zjtnslph4lj80000gn/T/RtmpZ7UFC7/downloaded_packages’ "

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, the 9th line (if I've counter correctly) of the install log spells out the error: the rgeos package depends on the geos software (that had nothing to do with R) to be installed. I'm not really experienced with Mac OS, but I bet you can Google for how to install geos there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much for the lead. I followed the instructions on the RForge page http://tlocoh.r-forge.r-project.org/mac_rgeos_rgdal.html - with the only difference being that for some reason the install of rgeos from the bash would only work if I removed the '.gz' from the file name. I don't understand why! Thanks again.